# unicity of a 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry

I read somewhere that if the 1st cohomology group of a manifold is trivial, then it contains a 1-form that is unique up to an exact form.

Is this statement true?

Thank you!

Comment: If the first de Rham cohomology group is trivial, then every closed one-form is exact, but there are plenty of non-exact one-forms.

Comment: Are you sure? if the first Rham cohomology group is trivial, then every closed form is exact, there can be no non-exact 1-form, since the Rham  cohomology group is the quotient of closed forms over exact forms. Could you please give details?

Comment: The point is that not every form is closed.